# Convert swift Xcode project into importable cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have a Xcode project and it's running well.
But now I want to convert my Xcode project into importable cocoapods, so I can import same cocoapods in multiple Xcode project and create new separate app with same features. (by changing some UI configuration only)

(Basically, I want to move whole app/project into cocoapods, including storyboards, assets and all files. so I can create another similar app by just re-branding UI)

Can someone please help me how to configure and setup for this kind of structure?

Thanks.